# How do I Get Faster Collisions From A List?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

Hi I am fairly new to python (been using it for a couple months now) and I was wondering how do I get faster collision from a list. I have a map which is a simple 2D array with objects and a have a camera Rectangle that checks if any of the Rect objects have collided and I was trying to do the same for player movement but it lagged to hell even on a small 120 by 90 map
so how do I speed this up with just using the CPU.

```
for x in range(gridLength):
    for y in range(gridHeight):
        if cameraRect.colliderect(grid[x][y].Rect):
            grid[x][y].draw(screen,((x * 16 + (WINDOWWIDTH / 2 - 16)) - playerRect.left),((y * 16) - playerRect.top + (WINDOWHEIGHT / 2 - 16)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a spatial index, such as a quadtree.  This allows you to efficiently query which objects collide with a given AABB (axis-aligned bounding box), and then you can do more sophisticated tests afterwards if the objects are not equal to their AABBs -- if they're circles, for example.

Here is an example implementation from the PyGame Wiki: http://www.pygame.org/wiki/QuadTree (you'll have to undo the HTML entity quoting in the sample code)

Alternatively, you could drop in a physics engine that someone else wrote.  It's an enormous amount of work, you know, to write a physics engine.  You might be surprised how much work it is even for simple 2D games.

If you use tiles for level data, you can also just store the tiles in a 2D array, and check for nonzero tiles in the given rect.  Something like:

```
def hit_test(x, y, xsize, ysize):
    xmin = (x - xsize//2) // tile_size
    xmax = (x + xsize//2) // tile_size
    ymin = (y - ysize//2) // tile_size
    ymax = (y + ysize//2) // tile_size
    for xtile in range(xmin, xmax):
        for ytile in range(xmin, xmax):
            if tiles[xtile][ytile] != 0:
                COLLISION
```